# What number to expect in the completion handler of NSAlert?

Tags: nsalert

I am curious what constant is passed to completion handler in NSAlert method

```
- (void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow completionHandler:(void (^)(NSModalResponse returnCode))handler
```

Is it a number like NSModalResponseStop=-1000 or NSModalResponseAbort=-1001 ?
How can I know what button was pressed if there are more than one button in the alert?

Answer (score 1):

The button return values are the same as for `beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`
. Possible values are listed under "Button Return Values" in the [NSAlert documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Button_Return_Values):

> An alert’s return values for buttons are position dependent. The following constants describe the return values for the first three buttons on an alert (assuming a language that reads left to right).

`enum {
   NSAlertFirstButtonReturn  = 1000,
   NSAlertSecondButtonReturn  = 1001,
   NSAlertThirdButtonReturn  = 1002
};`